# How to install APK from local server URL in phone without prompt to install screen?

Tags: android, sdk, apk

I am creating app like play store and will publish all our applications on this application. so our internal employee will get all our application in one place and then they can install or update app from this app. I have created the following code with the help of URL mentioned below. Code running successfully but nothing happening. Am I doing something wrong ?

I call below function on install button click like below

```
installPackage(getApplicationContext() , app_url);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548442/7223676

```
public static boolean installPackage(final Context context, final String url)
            throws IOException {
        //Use an async task to run the install package method
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
                    }
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                                PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
                    }

                    // set params
                    int sessionId = 0;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
                    }
                    PackageInstaller.Session session = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
                    }
                    OutputStream out = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
                    }
                    //get the input stream from the url
                    HttpURLConnection apkConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                    InputStream in = apkConn.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
                    int c;
                    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        session.fsync(out);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    //you can replace this intent with whatever intent you want to be run when the applicaiton is finished installing
                    //I assume you have an activity called InstallComplete
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info", "somedata");  // for extra data if needed..
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, generator.nextInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        session.commit(i.getIntentSender());
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.e("AppStore","Error when installing application. Error is " + ex.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
        task.execute(null,null);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It is not possible to install APK without prompt unless your app is a system app, or it gains root rights.

Comment: How can i make my app system app or root rights ?

Comment: you can embed your app into the device firmware, and flash the firmware into the device. As for root - you need to root the device (the way to do that differs per device), and then grant your app root permissions with some root permission manager.

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedback. will read about thi that how can i make my app as a system app

Comment: `you can embed your app into the device firmware, and flash the firmware into the device.` - system app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have root access of the device? From the link which you are following
[How to Install android app programatically without prompt,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462853/how-to-install-android-app-programatically-without-prompt/50548442#50548442)

It is clearly mentioned that

"Another way to install an app programatically without prompts **assuming you have root access** would be as follows"

Try getting the root access of your device first and then do what you are doing.

On a side not, if you succeed with the method you are following, it will not help you in any way. You will not be able to root every employ's device and this method will not work from them, unless you have some links with OEMs which by default add your application with the Android Os.

**ALSO :** For [Implementing Google Play Application Silent Install Feature On Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281308/implementing-google-play-application-silent-install-feature-on-android)

> Silent install on Google Experience devices is only possible by Google
>   Play. More generally, only stores that come preloaded on your hardware
>   can accomplish this, since they need to use the operating system's
>   signing key.
>
> This is for security reasons. Users need to be able to accept
>   permissions for new installations. The OS has no way to verify whether
>   non-official stores have properly done this.
>
> Third-party applications must use PackageManager to install new apps,
>   which will display permissions on your behalf and require an explicit
>   user approval.
>
> Attempting to circumvent this may fall under the "prohibited actions"
>   clause of the Google Play DDA, which puts your developer account at
>   risk for suspension. Don't do it.

Comment: can you please suggest what play store is doing ?

Comment: play store is a system app so it has INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

Comment: Playstore is a default Application handled by google and have root access.

Comment: Ok Thanx for your answer.

Comment: @Nitesh just wondering but what makes you think the Play Store has root access to your system?

Comment: @Zun by root access i mean system level rights. INSTALL_PACKAGES Permission as Manohar has mentioned. Also please refer my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to "skip" prompts without setting your device in Factory testing-mode. It varies from device to device how that is achieved and usually requires factory reset.

What I would recommend is to have a look at ADB-solution. By using ADB, you can install what ever program you want into the device as long it is in developer mode (which I assume is not a problem) easily from the computer. I know, this is not the solution to solve your specific problem, but I would have a look on that.